# Selecting multiple images from gallery is showing some error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, gallery

I have used the below code to select multiple images

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
```

On Activity Result

```
     ArrayList<String> mArrayUri=new ArrayList<>();
    if(data.getData()!=null){

        Uri mImageUri=data.getData();
       // Toast.makeText(this, mImageUri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String path=getImageFilePath2(mImageUri);
        mArrayUri.add(path);

    }else{
        if(data.getClipData()!=null){
            ClipData mClipData=data.getClipData();

            for(int i=0;i<mClipData.getItemCount();i++){

                ClipData.Item item = mClipData.getItemAt(i);
                Uri uri = item.getUri();
                String path=getImageFilePath2(uri);
                mArrayUri.add(path);
           //     Toast.makeText(this, uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("TAg",path);


            }
            Log.v("LOG_TAG", "Selected Images"+ mArrayUri.size());
        }

    }
```

It is working fine in:

[image]

with only Images tag but neither in gallery or photos or in InternalStorage/Camera/ Pictures. The problem becomes worse with mobile which does not show image tags  like:

[image]

Comment: It is pretty unclear which problem you face. Should we guess?

Comment: The problem is quite clear my app is working fine when we press images button as shown in first photo .But it does not work for "gallery "or "photos " button .The second photo does not  contain "images" button so my app does not work.

Comment: Your problem is completely unclear. If you do not want to elaborate ...

Comment: I have elaborated much .If you want to ask ,ask clearly what you do not understand.

Comment: If you want help then elaborate.